# Expect script erroring from Nagios, but good from cli

Tags: expect, nagios

I'm now learning Expect to try to automate a check on a remote system under Nagios Core, and while the script runs perfectly from the 'nagios' user account (which is what Nagios runs its commands under), the script errors under a Nagios run. In fact, the script run from the command line worked stright away without much drama - but now I've spent 3 days trying to figure out what's going wrong under Nagios.

I've determined that the CLI version sees the response from the `send "aaa test-server...` command, but the Nagios run doesn't and just times out. I've written things to the logfile to try to determine what I've done wrong, and I just can't see it. (I've disabled responses back to Nagios because that'll confuse it, but they're seen and used in the script.)

**Sequence I'm trying to automate:**

```
nagios:~# ssh accountname@192.168.1.20
accountname@192.168.1.20's password:
Last login: Wed Mar 27 03:43:03 2013 from 192.168.1.14
(Aruba3400) >en
Password:***********
(Aruba3400) #aaa test-server mschapv2 tester account1 password1
Authentication Successful
(Aruba3400) #exit
(Aruba3400) >exitConnection closed by foreign host.
Connection to 192.168.1.20 closed.
```

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# turn on logging output
log_user 0
log_file /tmp/output.txt
# set Variables
set password SomeThingOrOther
set useracct accountname
set ipaddr 192.168.1.20
set timeout 9

match_max -d 10000
# now connect to remote UNIX box (ipaddr) with given script to execute
spawn -noecho /usr/bin/ssh $useracct@$ipaddr
# Look for password prompt
expect "assword:"
# Send password aka $password
send "$password\n"
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we're at the prompt
expect "Aruba3400"
send "\r"
#send_log "log: 1st password entered.\n"

# Look for password prompt again, send Enable req
expect "Aruba3400"
send "en\r"
expect "assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect "(Aruba3400) #"
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we're at the prompt
send "\r"
expect "#"

send_log "log: Sent auth command.\n"
send "aaa test-server mschapv2 tester account1 password1\r"

# at next line, nagios run times out; command line runs fine
expect -timeout 9 "Successful"
# printout some debugs to logs whether it works or times out
send_log "log 0: $expect_out(0,string)\n"
send_log "log x: $expect_out(buffer)\n"

#---stock exit here so I can see some output, fix it later----
set TIME [exec date +%H:%M:%S]
log_user 1
send_user "Time: $TIME\n"
send_log "-----------------------\n"
exit 0
```

**Output of logs file:**

```
-----------------------
log: Sent auth command.
log 0: Successful
log x: aaa test-server mschapv2 tester account1 password1

Authentication Successful     <-- this is from the cli (works!)
Time: 16:00:02
-----------------------
log: Sent auth command.
log 0: #
log x:
(Aruba3400) #                 <-- this is under Nagios (timeout)
Time: 16:00:29
-----------------------
```

Can anyone provide me some clues as to what is going wrong here?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Any request that is sent from the nagios interface there are also logged. And also you can see the logs that are being generated by the nagios. It will have the exact problem string that your application is facing. if you can paste that error string here we can understand what the problem is.

Comment: I assume you mean `/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log`? It shows nothing - it will only show events that don't return a "0" from a Nagios check. It won't see an error because I set the timeout for 9 seconds so it wouldn't hang even when it doesn't work right. The output file I create for debugging purposes for each attempt shows that there's a difference between the cli and running under Nagios. That's where the problem lies - internal to the expect script, which is different between run environments. Once I determine what's wrong in the script, I can continue on and finish the program.

Comment: you can check system logs also which are located at /var/log. It might also contain exact problem string.

Comment: /var/log/messages contains nothing about this either. Since it doesn't error to Nagios or the system, it's not showing up in any logs. And it won't timeout to Nagios because I've shortened the normal timeout. If I didn't set it, Nagios would error, and its message would be "error: timeout" which doesn't help me because I KNOW it's doing this. The error is in expect and how in one case it's catching the anticipated string, and in the other it's not seeing it at all. I probably should turn on some debugging in Expect and see what it shows me, but I haven't got there yet. Any other suggestions?

Comment: A random guess is check permissions on script file. Make sure nagios is able to access and execute it.

Comment: At the command line, type 'env | grep -i proxy', what does that return?  Also, check the access_log and error_log on the remote web server.